# Responding to API requests with much complexity

Tags: c#, .net, generics, api

So having used the SE API multiple times, I like how all responses are in a `Wrapper` object, and for my own API design I figured it was a good method to follow.

Of course, I also wanted to abstract everything out so that common actions could be handled in a simple manner, so that I wouldn't need to write the same boilerplate code multiple times. (Wrap the entire response generation in a `try`/`catch` block then serialize exceptions to JSON, etc.)

Of course, since the inside of the `try`/`catch` block differs for each request, I needed a way to deal with that.

I got the idea to use a `Request` class which had a `ProcessRequest()` method that would call a `DoWork()` method which was implemented differently for each request.

Let's start with `Request<T>`:

```
public abstract class Request<T>
    where T : IBaseModel
{
    private ResponseType _responseType;

    public Request(HttpContext context)
    {
        var responseTypeString = context.Request.QueryString["FileType"] ?? string.Empty;
        _responseType = Utilities.Extensions.ResponseTypeExtensions.FromString(responseTypeString);
    }

    public string ProcessRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            var response = DoWork();
            var responseWrapped = BuildWrapper(response);
            var responseString = "";

            switch (_responseType)
            {
                // For the Delimited Serializer types, serialize ONLY the Items. The Delimited Serializer doesn't support serializing graph objects like JSON and XML do.
                case ResponseType.Csv:
                    responseString = DelimitedSerializer.CsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                    break;
                case ResponseType.Psv:
                    responseString = DelimitedSerializer.PsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                    break;
                case ResponseType.Tsv:
                    responseString = DelimitedSerializer.TsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                    break;
                // For the JSON and XML types, serailize the entire response.
                case ResponseType.Json:
                    JsonSerialization.Serialize(responseWrapped, ref responseString);
                    break;
                case ResponseType.Xml:
                    XmlSerialization.Serialize(responseWrapped, ref responseString);
                    break;
            }

            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Exception(e);
        }
    }

    private static string Exception(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is ArgumentException)
        {
            return ArgumentException((ArgumentException)exception);
        }

        return SerializeWrapper(BuildErrorWrapper(new ExceptionResponse(exception)));
    }

    private static string SerializeWrapper<TItem>(ApiResponseWrapper<TItem> wrapper)
        where TItem : IBaseModel
    {
        string response = "";
        JsonSerialization.Serialize(wrapper, ref response);
        return response;
    }

    private static ApiResponseWrapper<TItem> BuildErrorWrapper<TItem>(TItem item)
        where TItem : IBaseModel
    {
        var wrapper = new ApiResponseWrapper<TItem>();
        wrapper.Items.Add(item);
        wrapper.IsError = true;

        AddRateLimits(wrapper);

        return wrapper;
    }

    private static ApiResponseWrapper<TItem> BuildWrapper<TItem>(IEnumerable<TItem> items)
        where TItem : IBaseModel
    {
        var wrapper = new ApiResponseWrapper<TItem>();
        wrapper.Items.AddRange(items);
        wrapper.IsError = false;

        AddRateLimits(wrapper);

        return wrapper;
    }

    private static void AddRateLimits<TItem>(ApiResponseWrapper<TItem> wrapper)
        where TItem : IBaseModel
    {
        wrapper.QuotaMax = int.MaxValue;
        wrapper.QuotaRemaining = int.MaxValue;
    }

    private static string ArgumentException(ArgumentException exception) => SerializeWrapper(BuildErrorWrapper(new ArgumentExceptionResponse(exception)));

    protected abstract IEnumerable<T> DoWork();
}
```

The idea is to allow a derived class to implement it's own `DoWork()` method which will be run by the `Request<T>.ProcessRequest()` method.

To use it, an `IHttpHandler` has to simply do the following:

```
public class SiteHistory : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var request = new SiteHistoryRequest(context);
        var response = request.ProcessRequest();

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(response);
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Where `SiteHistoryRequest` would do all the major work and such.

This also means each type of request can be reused for multiple endpoints, with different parameters specified. (The base `Request<T>` cares not about any of this, it only cares about the core processing.)

Finally, here's what a sample implementation might look like (this endpoint isn't fully implemented, don't review it yet):

> ```
> public class SiteHistoryRequest : Request<SiteHistoryResponseItem>
> {
>     private const string _defaultFields = "Date,TotalQuestions,TotalAnswers,QuestionAnswerRate,AnswerAcceptRate,AnswersPerQuestion";
>
>     private string _fields;
>     private string _site;
>
>     public SiteHistoryRequest(HttpContext context)
>         : base(context)
>     {
>         _fields = context.Request.QueryString["Fields"] ?? _defaultFields;
>         _site = context.Request.QueryString["Site"];
>     }
>
>     protected override ApiResponseWrapper<SiteHistoryResponseItem> DoWork()
>     {
>         if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_site))
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentException("The 'Site' parameter is required and cannot be empty.", "Site");
>         }
>
>         return new ApiResponseWrapper<SiteHistoryResponseItem>();
>     }
> }
> ```

This satisfies two of my requirements:

1. All endpoints can use the same code and general implementation, and satisfy the file-type serialization requirements.
2. All errors will be gracefully handled and returned to the user as a JSON object.

Any comments welcome, though I would greatly appreciate any comments/advice on the design pattern itself.

Comment: Well, you should actually already know how to write a good title :-P

Comment: @t3chb0t Better? ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `is` operator and if it evaluates to `true` and then you cast the type the code behind is doing it twice. A better way would involve a soft cast using `as` and a `null` check like so

```
private static string Exception(Exception exception)
{
    var argumentException = exception as ArgumentException;
    if (argumentException != null)
    {
         return ArgumentException(argumentException );
    }

    return SerializeWrapper(BuildErrorWrapper(new ExceptionResponse(exception)));
}
```

As mentioned by you `is` would be faster than `as` I measured this myself, using the following two methods

```
static int FindSumWithCast(object[] values)
{

    int sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in values)
    {
        if (o is TestClass)
        {
            int x = ((TestClass)o).Value;
            sum += x;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

static int FindSumWithAs(object[] values)
{

    int sum = 0;
    foreach (object o in values)
    {
        TestClass x = o as TestClass;
        if (x != null)
        {
            sum += x.Value;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

with `TestClass` looking like so

```
class TestClass
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public TestClass(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

and called both methods in my timing soulution with an `object[]` created like so

```
const int Size = 30000000;
object[] values = new object[Size];
for (int i = 0; i < Size - 1; i += 2)
{
    values[i] = "";
    values[i + 1] = new TestClass(1);
}
```

In your quote Jon Skeet stated that `is` would be 20 times faster than `as` but this seems only if value types are involved.

My mesurements resulted in:

is: 0.095 ms
as: 0.091 ms

but now enough with that.

I thought about this some time and just thought, why don't you just catch the correct exception ?

Like so

```
public string ProcessRequest()
{
    try
    {
        var response = DoWork();
        var responseWrapped = BuildWrapper(response);
        var responseString = "";

        switch (_responseType)
        {
            // For the Delimited Serializer types, serialize ONLY the Items. The Delimited Serializer doesn't support serializing graph objects like JSON and XML do.
            case ResponseType.Csv:
                responseString = DelimitedSerializer.CsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                break;
            case ResponseType.Psv:
                responseString = DelimitedSerializer.PsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                break;
            case ResponseType.Tsv:
                responseString = DelimitedSerializer.TsvSerializer.Serialize(responseWrapped.Items);
                break;
            // For the JSON and XML types, serailize the entire response.
            case ResponseType.Json:
                JsonSerialization.Serialize(responseWrapped, ref responseString);
                break;
            case ResponseType.Xml:
                XmlSerialization.Serialize(responseWrapped, ref responseString);
                break;
        }

        return responseString;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        return ArgumentException(e);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Exception(e);
    }
}

private static string Exception(Exception exception)
{
    return SerializeWrapper(BuildErrorWrapper(new ExceptionResponse(exception)));
}
```

Comment: @EBrown the difference seems to be marginal and barely noticable even with 50.000.000 iterations [C# 'is' operator performance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1817083/235671) - I think next time I use the `is` because it looks nicer ;-) how did you test the performance?

Comment: @EBrown In my own testing `as` is faster than `is` (though marginally as mentioned). I'd be interested in knowing how you determined the opposite.

Comment: @eurotrash "I'd always assumed that doing one check would be faster than two, but it appears that's not the case, ... When writing a quick benchmark that summed all the integers within an array of type `object[]`, where only a third of the values were actually boxed integers, using `is` and then a cast ended up being *20 times faster* than using the `as` operator." C# In Depth by Jon Skeet, Page 123.

Comment: @t3chb0t See the above comment.

Comment: @EBrown I'd say this is a good news because I like the `is` better then then `as`.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: @EBrown Thanks for the source. I guess the answer (for the off-topic question of "is `is` faster than `as`") is really "it depends on the input".

Answer (score 6):

**Serialization**

Where there's a switch there is usually an indication of a missing interface. In your case you could perfectly define a serializer interface:

```
public interface ISerializer
{
    public ResponseType ResponseType { get; }
    public string Serialize(object items);
}
```

and make the `Request` class extendable:

```
class Request
{
    // or a dictionary or whatever you like
    // you could also pass a collection to the constructor and make it immutable
    public List<ISerializer> Serializers { get; set; }

    public string ProcessRequest()
    {
        return Serializers
            .Where(x => x.ResponseType == abc)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Serialize(input));
    }
}
```

---

**Constructor**

> ```
> public Request(HttpContext context)
> ```

We don't normally use public constructors in abstract classes. It should be protected.

---

**Exception formatting**

I don't like the exception formatting that the `Request` is currently responsible for. It doesn't look like it belongs there. The `Request` should take an exception formatter via DI. Formatting exceptions is a different matter and it doesn't fit well into a `Request`.

---

**Naming**

> ```
> return Exception(e);
> ```

This is a very misleading and unclear name for a method. To understand what it does I had to first look at its source code. `FormatException` would be much better because its what it actually does.

> ```
> IBaseModel
> ```

I'm not happy with this name either. It looks like it should rather be the name of the class `RequestBase` and not of the interface. For an interface a name like `IRequest` would be fine.

Comment: `IBaseModel` is used in a lot of other places for other things.

Comment: @EBrown could you post it too? I'm curious about what it does. I still think it might be too general.

Comment: It's literally an empty interface. I only use it for generic restrictions.

Comment: @EBrown this is a very questionable design ;-]